# android string gallery can't display from beginning of the screen

Tags: android

i had creating string gallery but android string gallery can't display from beginning of the screen. it displayed. any solution??

thanks inn advance.

```
private Context cont;
private String [] stringid=new String[]{"Index-Nifty","Positional calls","Intraday calls","InvestmentIdea","Optional calls","BTST-STBT calls"};     

public TabGallary(Context c) {
    cont = c;
}

public int getCount(){
    return stringid.length;
}   

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {                                
    TextView view = new TextView(cont);                   

    //Fixing width & height for String to display
    view.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(125, 20));
    view.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
    view.setText(stringid[position]);                       
    view.setSingleLine();   

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    startActivity(intent);
    return view;
}

private void startActivity(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey.. for dat u have to use `LayoutInflater`

first u create an XML file "demo.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget44"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt1_gvi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#051b4d"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColorHighlight="#656565"
        android:textSize="10sp">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

now ur adaptor class should be like following..
here instead of context u have to pass activity..
eg
instead of `public TabGallary(Context c)` u have to `public TabGallary(Activity a)`

```
    public Activity activity;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    private String [] stringid=new String[]{"Index-Nifty","Positional calls","Intraday calls","InvestmentIdea","Optional calls","BTST-STBT calls"};     

    public TabGallary(Activity a) {     
        activity = a;
        inflater =  (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return stringid.length;
    }   

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)   
    {           
      View v;                     
      if (convertView == null) 
      {  
           LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
           v = li.inflate(R.layout.demo, null);
           TextView tv1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt1_gvi); 
           tv1.setText(stringid[position]);
           v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
           {                    
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                  // Call intent or perform ur activity;                
                    }
           });      
      }
      else 
      {
       v= convertView;
      }     

      return v;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is displaying from the first. It may be because you have set Layoutparams for Gallery you are not able to see it.

Comment: meance i just delete to set layout??

Comment: it dont work.. it just overlap string and starts from approx mid.

Comment: post the part of the code where you display the gallery in your main view